# Ontology inference: can a class be represented as the intersection of a mix of object properties and resources?

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web, ontology

I am using Jena for developing an ontology whose base prefix we assume to be `PREFIX example: <http://example.com#>`. Within this ontology I have a `example:Algorithm` ontology class. I want to define an `example:LoadCloudAlgorithm` class as such: `intersectionOf(example:Algorithm, example:hasFileParameter)`, the latter being an object property.

Suppose that an individual is created as a result of one execution of this algorithm, `example:LoadCloudAlgorithmExecution-1` that `example:hasFileParameter example:file-1`.

**Problem:** The `OWL_DL` reasoner that I use, [Openllet](https://github.com/Galigator/openllet), does not infer that `<example:LoadCloudAlgorithmExecution-1> <rdf:type> <example:LoadCloudAlgorithm>`. Check the code below:

```
/**
     * Constructing ontology schema, meaning the ontology classes, object properties and
     * restrictions
     */

    final String EXAMPLE_NS = "http://example.com#";

    OntModel schema = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);

    ObjectProperty hasParameter = schema.createObjectProperty(EXAMPLE_NS + "hasParameter");
    ObjectProperty hasFileParameter = schema.createObjectProperty(EXAMPLE_NS + "hasFileParameter");

    hasFileParameter.addSuperProperty(hasParameter);

    OntClass file = schema.createClass(EXAMPLE_NS + "File");

    Restriction r = schema.createAllValuesFromRestriction(null, hasFileParameter, file);    // parameters only in the range defined by file

    /* Algorithm class and sub-class */

    OntClass algorithm = schema.createClass(EXAMPLE_NS + "Algorithm");

    // loadCloud is described esentially by the logic relationship (algorithm AND hasFileParameter)

    OntClass loadCloud = schema.createIntersectionClass(EXAMPLE_NS + "LoadCloud", schema.createList((new RDFNode[] {
        algorithm, r
    })));

    /**
     * Constructing the data model: nowhere below is it specified that example:LoadCloud-1 is a sub-class
     * of example:LoadCloud; the only thing known is that it is an algorithm and that it has a property
     * example:hasFileParameter, which is example:File-1
     */

    OntModel data = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);

    Individual loadCloudInd = data.createIndividual(EXAMPLE_NS + "LoadCloud-1", algorithm);
    Individual fileInd = data.createIndividual(EXAMPLE_NS + "File-1", file);

    loadCloudInd.addProperty(hasFileParameter, fileInd);

    /**
     * Inferring the model: according to the output, inferring is correct
     */

    Reasoner reasoner = PelletReasonerFactory.theInstance().create();

    reasoner.bindSchema(schema);

    InfModel inferredModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, data);

    boolean success = false;

    Resource infModelLoadCloudRes = inferredModel.getResource(loadCloudInd.getURI());

    for (StmtIterator i = inferredModel.listStatements(infModelLoadCloudRes, (Property) null, (RDFNode) null); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Statement stmt = i.nextStatement();

        if (stmt.getPredicate().hasURI(loadCloud.getURI())) success = true;
    }

    assertTrue(success);
```

What is the logical inconsistency here?

Comment: Openllet is OWL2 Reasoner, In OW2 there are only ObjectIntersectionOf and DataIntersectionOf logical construction. The last one is for defining new data range expression. The [first one](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Intersection_of_Class_Expressions) can not contain object property in the last part, it is only for class expressions. But OWL2 allows [punnings](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12:_Punning) and it seems to be okay, when the entity is both an object property and a class.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by following the suggestion of the comment to my initial question: in addition to the `example:hasParameter` object property I created the ontology class `example:hasParameter`. On the creation of my individual, I added two classes to it: `example:Algorithm` which was initially there, and also `example:hasParameter`. I am feeling as though this causes redundancy though and still looking for a better answer.